# Looking for a Javascript, Php IDE

Tags: javascript, php, ide, open-source

I need a free or opensource IDE to develop javacript (openlayers, jquery, js-test-driver, jasmine), php (Yii framework), no Flash. So far, I'm between Aptana 3 and Netbeans 7. MySql is my db backend. It will be running on Windows.

Criteria to use:
reasonable performance, most-important features (autocomplete, refactoring, testing/svn/ant integration, highlight errors, go to function//method, find usages of a function/method)

Could you recommend any? 
Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing to Eclipse I've chosen Netbeans and worked a long time using it.
It's perfect for Java, PHP, JavaScript.
I've just needed to move to Eclipse when started to write the Python applications.

Both of them may need make some [tweaks](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqSlowNetBeans) to improve the speed and performance.

**Update about my Eclipse experience:**

Maybe I'm doing something wrong in Eclipse, but seems that Netbeans is performing the code completion for JavaScript code more intelligently than Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

I'd definitely recommend NetBeans

**UPDATE:**

.. even though you mentioned 'free', I'd give IntelliJ a shot. You get 30 days free (and then 30 min at a time before it restarts).

I've not done any PHP with IntelliJ (only Java and Groovy/Grails), but if it's handling of PHP is as exquisite as the other languages, it might be a good long term option. I still use NetBeans a lot and I'm very glad I splurged on IntelliJ.